# performSegueWithIdentifier in if statement isn't working

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement

I have made a funtion for my IBAction with a performSegueWithIdentifier and it worked perfectly fine until now it always shows the alert but it also perform the segue to the next view. I don't know what I have done wrong. The identifier is wright in the MainView. I can't finde any answer to solve this.

```
@IBOutlet weak var backgroundImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var logInPassword: UITextField!
@IBAction func registerButton(sender: AnyObject) {
}

@IBAction func login(sender: AnyObject) {

    if logInPassword.text!.isEmpty {
        let alertNoPasswordLogIn = UIAlertView()
        alertNoPasswordLogIn.title = "Passwort fehlt"
        alertNoPasswordLogIn.message = "Bitte geben sie ein Passwort ein!"
        alertNoPasswordLogIn.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")
        alertNoPasswordLogIn.show()
    } else {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Login", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried printing the `logInPassword.text!` to see wether it is actually empty or not

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the `alertNoPasswordLogin` line and look what's in the text field.

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Is it getting to the line to run it? Can you put a breakpoint there? Is there a segue called "Login" etc... You'll have to explain what is happening and what is going wrong.

Comment: sorry, there is a segue called "login" and the actual problem is that it sees the textfield is empty but it is performing the segue. It shows the alert AND it performs the segue

Comment: Try to remove the segue and add it again @Thobbit

Comment: @RashwanL    I tried but it didn't change anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say you connected a segue from your login button to the new scene *and* connected the button's action to your `login(:)` action. This would result in the action being fired (and following the `true` branch of your `if` statement) *and* the segue being fired.

What you probably meant to do was to drag the segue connection from the view controller (not the login button, which will *always* fire the segue) to the new scene. That will then result in firing ONLY the action but also allows you to have a named segue in your storyboard that you can call from your code.

Only drag segues from an action control (like a button) if you *always* want it to be performed as the control's action (because it always will be).

Comment: Yes a cleaner way (+1)

Comment: Thank you, you have helped me a lot. I didn't know that buttons are working like this

Answer (score 1):

You have connected your segue with button, so when you press button the segue fired irrelevant of the code you put in you UIButton Action, to disable that you have to use below code

```
func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String, sender: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    if (identifier == "Login") {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: This just needlessly adds code since the button's action is already set to his `login(:)` action method. See my answer for a cleaner way.